# How do I serialize JSON with hyphen in key using Spring Boot?

Tags: json, spring-boot, serialization

I have the following JSON...

```
{
    "navigation-items":[
       {
           "title":"Title",
           "description":"This is the desc",
           "link":"http://google.com"
       }
    ]
}
```

I have the following Java

```
public class ExternalConfig {
    @SerializedName("navigation-items")
    private List<NavigationItem> items;

    public NavigationItem getNavItem(Integer index){
        return items.get(index);
    }

    public void putNavItem(NavigationItem item){
        items.add(item);
    }

    public Integer navItemSize(){
        return items == null ? 0 : items.size();
    }
}

...

@PostMapping("config")
@ResponseBody
public void setConfig(@RequestBody ExternalConfig config){
    System.out.println(config.navItemSize() > 0);
}
```

But when I send a request with the following body....

```
{
    "navigation-items":[
        {
            "title":"Title",
            "description":"This is the desc",
            "link":"http://google.com"
        },{
            "title":"Test 2",
            "description":"asdasdsadsadas",
            "link":"http://drudgereport.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I break in the endpoint items is null. How do I pass JSON with a hyphenated key to Spring Boot?

Comment: If all attributes adhere to the hyphen naming pattern; you can use PropertyNamingStrategy.KebabCaseStrategy

Answer (score 1):

Use @JsonProperty if u use spring-boot.

```
@JsonProperty("navigation-items")
private List<NavigationItem> items;
```

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here was that I wasn't including jackson-databind like this...

```
 compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:latest.release'
```

Not sure if there is a way to use GSON since I already had that but for now I will just use jackson.